# How to remove first two JSON objects from JSON file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, unset

I have a JSON file named 'jason_file.json' that is look like:

```
[
 {"name":"name1", "city":"city1", "country":"country1"},
 {"name":"name2", "city":"city2", "country":"country2"},
 {"name":"name3", "city":"city3", "country":"country3"},
 {"name":"name4", "city":"city4", "country":"country4"},
 {"name":"name5", "city":"city5", "country":"country5"}
]
```

Using for loop, I want to remove first two objects from file and save remaining objects in the same order in the 'jason_file.json'. Required result should be:

```
[
 {"name":"name3", "city":"city3", "country":"country3"},
 {"name":"name4", "city":"city4", "country":"country4"},
 {"name":"name5", "city":"city5", "country":"country5"}
]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I'd use `file_get_contents`, `file_put_contents`, `json_decode`, `json_encode` and some `unset`. Could you give it a go yourself? It is excellent practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$json = '[
 {"name":"name1", "city":"city1", "country":"country1"},
 {"name":"name2", "city":"city2", "country":"country2"},
 {"name":"name3", "city":"city3", "country":"country3"},
 {"name":"name4", "city":"city4", "country":"country4"},
 {"name":"name5", "city":"city5", "country":"country5"}
]'; //file_get_contents('jason_file.json');

$json = json_encode(array_slice(json_decode($json, true), 2));
/*                              (1) decode the JSON string
                    <-----------
                    (2) cut off the first two elements
        <-----------
        (3) recode as JSON
*/

echo $json;

//file_put_contents('jason_file.json, $json);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/deb4f4ace66d0f):

```
[{"name":"name3","city":"city3","country":"country3"},{"name":"name4","city":"city4","country":"country4"},{"name":"name5","city":"city5","country":"country5"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

To make sure you end up with valid json, I would not edit the file manually.

Instead, read the file, parse the json, use `array_shift()` or something similar to remove the first two elements in the array, encode the resulting array as json and put it back in the file.

Answer (score 1):

Well firstly, you will want to pull the file into a string. So

```
$str = file_get_contents('/path/to/my/file');
```

Then you will want to decode the string contents.

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
```

Finally shift the array twice

```
$arr = array_shift($arr);
$arr = array_shift($arr);
```

Or alternatively, slice the array

```
$arr = array_slice($arr, 2);
```

Finally, you can place the json string back into a file.

```
$newJson = json_encode($arr);
file_put_contents('/path/to/saved/file', $newJson);
```

Hope this helps!